# How to add the incremental date value with respect to first row value in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

Input :

```
+------+--------+  
|Test  |01-12-20|  
|Ravi  |    null|  
|Son   |    null|
```

Expected output :

```
+------+--------+  
|Test  |01-12-20|  
|Ravi  |02-12-20|  
|Son   |03-12-20|
```

I tried with `.withColumn(col("dated"),date_add(col("dated"),1));`
But this result in NULL for all the columns values.

Could you please help me with getting the incremental values on the date second column?

Comment: is there an identifier column in your dataset? Is there only one row in your dataset with a date or are there others eg. row 1 has a date then row 45 has a date. If there are others, how should this be treated?

Comment: @zdev can you please accept my answer ? This really helps

Answer (score 3):

This will be a working solution for you

**Input**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("Test", "01-12-20"),("Ravi", None),("Son", None)],[ "col1","col2"])
df.show()
df = df.withColumn("col2", F.to_date(F.col("col2"),"dd-MM-yy"))
# a dummy col for window function
df = df.withColumn("del_col", F.lit(0))
_w = W.partitionBy(F.col("del_col")).orderBy(F.col("del_col").desc())
df = df.withColumn("rn_no", F.row_number().over(_w)-1)
# Create a column with the same date
df = df.withColumn("dated", F.first("col2").over(_w))

df = df.selectExpr('*', 'date_add(dated, rn_no) as next_date')
df.show()
```

**DF**

```
+----+--------+
|col1|    col2|
+----+--------+
|Test|01-12-20|
|Ravi|    null|
| Son|    null|
+----+--------+
```

**Final Output**

```
+----+----------+-------+-----+----------+----------+
|col1|      col2|del_col|rn_no|     dated| next_date|
+----+----------+-------+-----+----------+----------+
|Test|2020-12-01|      0|    0|2020-12-01|2020-12-01|
|Ravi|      null|      0|    1|2020-12-01|2020-12-02|
| Son|      null|      0|    2|2020-12-01|2020-12-03|
+----+----------+-------+-----+----------+----------+
```